# Python - Removing tuples by prefix and suffix from list

Tags: python, tuples, python-itertools

What's the fastest way to remove tuples from a python list (and update the list with the removed tuples) according to what the tuple starts with or ends with.

Example:

```
import itertools
l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l2 = ["d", "e", "f"]
tupl_lst = list(itertools.product(l1, l2))
tupl_lst
Out[42]: 
[('a', 'd'),
 ('a', 'e'),
 ('a', 'f'),
 ('b', 'd'),
 ('b', 'e'),
 ('b', 'f'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('c', 'e'),
 ('c', 'f')]
```

I want to remove all tuples that starts with `'a'` OR ends with `'f'` so that my output will look as follows:

```
[('b', 'd'),
 ('b', 'e'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('c', 'e')]
```

What is the fastest way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a list comprehension:

```
[t for t in tupl_lst if t[0]!='a' and t[1]!='f']
```

with `filter`:

```
list(filter(lambda t: t[0]!='a' and t[1]!='f',tupl_lst))
```

Comment: %timeit list(filter(lambda t: t[0]!='a' and t[1]!='f',tupl_lst))
1.3 µs ± 10.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each) %timeit [t for t in tupl_lst if t[0]!='a' and t[1]!='f']
665 ns ± 15.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each) looks like the simple list comprehension is faster

Answer (score 3):

You can even skip the `itertools.product()`and just use one list-comprehension:

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l2 = ["d", "e", "f"]

tupl_lst = [(x, y) for x in l1 for y in l2 if x!="a" and y!="f"]

#output
[('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the prefix (`a`) and suffix (`f`) altogether by iterating over slices of the lists.

```
[(x, y) for x in l1[1:] for y in l2[:-1]]
# [('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e')]
```